# Object or class type required in delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I try to convert string value to char array.
I write below code but get error that

> [Error] Unit1.pas(35): Record, object or class type required

on this line section `a := s.ToCharArray;`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
 a: array of char;
 s: String;
begin
 s:= Edit1.Text;
 a := s.ToCharArray;
end;
```

What is problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Delphi 7 there is no string helper, hence the compilation error you encounter. Use this instead

```
SetLength(a, Length(s));
Move(Pointer(s)^, Pointer(a)^, Length(s) * SizeOf(s[1]));
```

Now, `SizeOf(s[1])` is `1` in Delphi 7 so the multiplication isn't strictly necessary, but it does mean that your code will work correctly if ever you move to a Unicode Delphi.

Or, if the use of `Move` isn't to your taste, use a loop to copy the characters

```
SetLength(a, Length(s));
for i := 1 to Length(s) do
  a[i - 1] := s[i];
```

Comment: It's always a delight to see code snippets from really experienced Delphi developers, because there's perfection in every detail. Just look how gracefully David avoids possible range-check errors if `s` is empty, taking advantage of the fact that `SizeOf` is a compiler-intrinsic function!

Comment: @Andreas Very kind, I blush. You are right that this is experience. I've just been doing it so long now I've absorbed these idioms!